# Akka model supervision

Tags: scala, akka

I have a problem with managing supervision.

Let's say I have actor A which creates actor B and sends him a message.

```
 val B = context.actorOf(Props[B],"B")
 B ! RandomMessage(param1, param2)
```

B do so calculations or ask remote service. Basically it could fail with Exception.

```
 override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(loggingEnabled = false) {
case exception:NetworkException => {
  Restart
  // here I don't have access to param1 and param2 to send message again
}
```

}

It works fine, because child actor is restarted, but what if I want to retry this failed message. How can I do this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The message is available in `preRestart`.

```
override def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]) = {
    self ! message.get
    //to continue default behavior. ie, to restart all child actors
    //you could even manage how you deal with your child actor here instead of calling super.preRestart
    super.preRestart(reason, message) 
}
```

Make sure that you configure supervision strategy in such that a way that it doesnt fall into infinite loop.

**EDIT**

As @Viktor Klang mentioned, dont use `Option#get` instead use `Option#getOrElse` and handle the odd case.

Comment: I can use preRestart, but I'd have to cast message: Option[Any] to my command type. For now I have only one command, but later on I'll probably add more and there might be a problem

Comment: I am guessing you are already using pattern matching in your  `receive` method to handle messages. The same would be sufficient for messages from preRestart. Just make sure to use `Option#get`, instead of sending option itself.

Comment: Do *not* use Option.get, there's a reason why it is an option, it is not always available.